# In practice, does one need an IDP to rent a car in Mexico?

Tags: car-rentals, mexico, driving-licenses, german-citizens

I'm going to Cabo San Lucas soon and would like to rent a car for a few days while I'm there with my friends. I have a US driving license which is presumably accepted down there, but my friend has a German license. Is an IDP required to rent a car in Mexico if your license is not from Canada or the US?

Comment: I can't answer for renting a car in Mexico as I've never done it.  But I've never been asked for an IDP here, my New Zealand license has always been accepted - by police, military, immigration, Federales, insurance companies etc.  I did have an IDP, but never used it, not even once, so let it expire and never bothered with renewing it.  I think it's unlikely you'll be asked for one at a rental car company.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have paid for an IDL, and nobody ever wanted to see it; not in Mexico, not in the US, not in Canada, not in Russia, not in India. If they even know what it is, they decline to accept it, and ask for my "normal driver's license" (which is a German one, btw)

Rental car companies are having hundreds of international customers every day, and they are quite familiar with your national driver's license, even if you would come from a small and unknown country, if not, they will make do [it is much more important to have a credit card...]

So unless your driver's license is in a non-latin alphabet, save the money for an IDL.

Edit: yes, the official government recommendation is to *have an IDL*. I am just a random guy on the internet; but my recommendation based on experience is to save the money for it.

Comment: It is not just the rental companies that require IDLs, it is also the police if you are in an accident. And the official rules may be that without the right IDL you are considered to drive without a license. Paying for an IDL is the cheaper option.

Comment: @Willeke Police in Mexico don't ask for IDP, and won't look at it if you offer it.  They will ask for a license, be surprised if you look Caucasian and don't hand them a US license, and possibly will ask for an FMM (although even this is unlikely, unless it's specifically an INM checkpoint).

Comment: This answer is not just covering Mexico, it is an 'international' answer which happens to be placed under a question about Mexico. As long as the restriction to Mexico is not made in the answer, it is wrong advice.

Comment: @Willeke It is only wrong advice if there are rental car agencies in some country that require it.  Are there?  Perhaps if 1 or 2 countries do require it, then this answer is correct except for those 1 or 2 countries

Comment: It is not about rental companies requiring it. It is about it being a legal requirement in some countries, even when rental companies ignore it. When preparing for Brexit UK drivers were told to have their IDL with them, as they would be illegal to drive in the rest of Europe if Brexit happened while they were there, even though their license did not change overnight. (Brexit has not come to pass yet, so it has not been tested.)

Comment: @Willeke surely someone would know if IDP/IDL is actually required, given that millions of tourists drive around in Mexico and at least a few hundred of them get into accidents every year?

Comment: As the government only 'recommends' it (see citation at the other answer) it is obviously not _required_. this is identical for other countries.

Comment: @JonathanReezSupportsMonica, I repeat, this answer is international/world wide and as such a bad advice. (In case of Mexico an IDL is only advised, not required, in other countries it is required.)

Answer (score -1):

The German Embassy **recommends** having a *International Drivers Permit* (IDP) for driving in Mexico.

It also warns that the **Tourist Card FMM** is not always stamped upon entry from the USA. But since ID's are often checked inside Mexico, to make sure that it is stamped propery before continuing on into Mexico.

---

> **Führerschein**
>   Der Internationale Führerschein **wird empfohlen** und ist nur in Verbindung mit dem nationalen deutschen Führerschein gültig.
>
> > **driver's license**
> >     The international driver's license **is recommended** and is valid only in conjunction with the national German driver's license.

---

> **Touristenkarte FMM**
>   ...
>   **Ein- und Ausreise über die USA**
>   Bei der Einreise auf dem Landweg über die USA kann es vorkommen, dass Touristenkarten **nicht abgestempelt** werden. In diesem Fall muss dies, z. B. gegen Vorlage des Bustickets, beim Instituto Nacional de Migración des Grenzortes nachgeholt werden, dies ist z.B. in Tijuana auch im INM-Büro im Flughafen möglich.
>
> > **Tourist Card FMM**
> >     ...
> >     **Entry and exit via the USA**
> >     When entering the country via the US, it may happen that tourist cards **are not stamped**.  In this case, this must, for example, on presentation of the bus ticket, be made at the Instituto Nacional de Migración the border town, this is e.g.  in Tijuana also in the INM office in the airport possible.

---

> **Ausweispflicht**
>   Bei Personenkontrollen wird nicht nur der Ausweis verlangt, sondern auch die mexikanische Aufenthaltserlaubnis (Touristenkarte FMM, bzw. Langzeitaufenthaltstitel FM 2/3). **Ausländer sollten ihre mexikanische Aufenthaltserlaubnis jederzeit, zumindest als Kopie, bei sich führen (s.o.)**. Andernfalls besteht das Risiko, von der Einwanderungsbehörde in Gewahrsam genommen und ggf. abgeschoben zu werden.
>
> > **ID required**
> >     In the case of identity checks, not only the ID card is required, but also the Mexican residence permit (tourist card FMM or long-term residence permit FM 2/3). **Foreigners should carry their Mexican residence permit at any time [all times], at least as a copy (see above)**.  Otherwise, there is a risk of being detained by the Immigration Department and possibly deported.

---

**Sources**:

- [Mexiko: Reise- und Sicherheitshinweise - Auswärtiges Amt](https://mexiko.diplo.de/mx-de/themen/willkommen/laenderinfos/reise-sicherheit)

Comment: So is this a 'yes' or a 'no' answer to the posted question? What does it mean that an IDP is *recommended*? Which disadvantages would a driver face just having the German driver's license and not an IDP?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbo All sites that I found, give no definite yes/no answer. Some stated everything not in English needs one. I could not find an official Mexican site at all about who needs a IDP. Not following the recommendation could lead to charges of driving without a valid driver's licence. If the driving classes of the European driver's licence is different from that in Mexico, then some police official may not accept it.

Comment: There are millions of tourists driving around in Mexico every year. Surely people know by now if Mexican police checks for IDP? :)

Comment: @JonathanReezSupportsMonica Well, the German Embassy in  Mexico doesn't seem to know for sure, just as the Netherlands Automobile Club, since they both only **recommende** it. It may be officially allowed, but often nevertheless not accepted by individual police officers.

Comment: If driving without an IDP 'could lead to charges of driving without a valid driver's license', an IDP would be *required* and not merely *recommended*. I have noticed these odd 'recommendations' in German travel advisories before without finding a sufficient explanation of what is actually ment. Basically, an IDP will either be required or not. There does not seem to be any reasonable explanation why it should be 'recommended'.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbo What are you expecting here? An answer yes without any verified source? If you have problems with the given sources, complain to them.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I am expecting that if you don't know the answer, that you should not simply quote vague statements you have found using Google if you are not able to explain what exactly these statements mean.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbo The German Embassy in Mexico and the Dutch Automobile Associations statements are not **vage** sources. They are **official sources**, the latter who issues IDP. I also know what an Embassy recommendation means: **if you do not follow it,  you may regret it - but is up to you to deside**. I have also lived in Mexico and have seen what Mexican police stations look like in rural areas (and heard about how people inside are treated). Clear enough?

Comment: No sorry, it is absolutely not clear and you are refusing to answer my questions and ignoring my objections. It should be obvious, but neither German authorities, nor a Dutch automobile club are authorative sources for Mexican legal requirements and in this case, they don't even come with a clear statement. Both sources btw issue IDPs, so they will have a monetary benefit from every tourist jumping onto the 'recommendation' and have an IDP issued. May that be the reason for the recommendation?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbo The German Embassy does not issue IDP's. They give advice to their citizens on befe this question was asked. That advise is the main part of this answer. Sorry if you think that answers can only be a Yes or No. In the real world this is not so. I can live very well with the downvote given from those who think otherwise.

Comment: IDPs are in Germany issued by the license authority office responsible for your place of residence (and not by automobile clubs as in most other countries), so if you are actually resident in Mexico and need an IDP, I would very much assume that the embassy or a consulate is the place to go. Why can't you answer and/or keep to my questions and objections instead of with every comment invent and address new issues completely irrelevant for the discussion?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbo Your assumption is wrong, a  German Consulate will not issue to a German citizen who is a resident in Mexico a IDP, because as a resident of Mexico they are required to obtain a Mexican Driver's Licence. For any further questions, press the 'Ask Question' Button.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Yet again, your comment is completely irrelevant with regard to my objections against your answer. Why can't you answer and/or keep to my questions and objections instead of with every comment invent and address new issues completely irrelevant for the discussion? I would also appreciate if you write my name correctly when tagging me, so that I am notified about your comments.